# how can i run python code not in the terminal in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

im new to vs code , im making a simple ui app in python and when i run it , it runs in the terminal
but other ide's just open the ui , like visual studio workd but vs code is not.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Read through the docs https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Vscode itself is a lightweight editor, and the terminals used are still included in the system.

So when you run the file, it uses the system terminal, not that vscode comes with a terminal just like other ides.

Read this [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_terminal-shells) for more details.